# Terminating while loop with empty stdin in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm running a `while` loop in a Perl script that needs to terminate when nothing is entered for `stdin`. I've tried all kinds of possibilities, most recently `while($in ne "")`, but nothing works. What is the correct way to terminate a while loop if the given condition (stdin) is simply nothing (just enter is pressed at the prompt)?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I need a loop similar to the below code, and I need to terminate the while loop if nothing is entered for the prompt.

```
print "Enter your information: ";
$in = <>;

while($in) {
    #do stuff

    print "Enter your information: ";
    $in = <>;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (my $in = <>) {

  chomp($in);
  length($in) or last;

  # ..
}
```

Comment: Never mind, this works exactly as it should. Thank you!

Comment: This solution does nothing that a simple `while (<>) { ... }` won't do

Comment: OP mentioned lexical and stdin

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers already have you covered, but to more completely duplicate your code, you can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (1) {
    print "Enter your information: ";
    my $in = <STDIN>;
    chomp($in);

    last if $in eq '';
}
```

Comment: That will loop endlessly if the user enters end-of-file

Comment: Please educate me, How does one enter end-of-file?  The only edge case I can determine is if someone does Ctnl-Z enter, they'll get a Use of uninitialized value warning.  If they cared enough they could do <STDIN> // '' to fix that, but I don't think it's important enough to address given the nature of this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (my $in = <STDIN>) {
    print "got: '$in'\n";
    chomp($in);
    last if $in eq '';
}

print "done.\n"
```

Comment: I just updated the main post with more information; this unfortunately does not work. Does the additional information help to figure out my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
while () {

  print "Enter your information: ";
  chomp(my $in = <>);
  last unless $in;

  # do stuff with $in
}
```

Comment: @mpapec: Understood: `"\n"` is true. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: `last unless $in` -- this will exit the loop if user enters `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $in = '';
while (1) {
  print "Enter your information: ";
  $in = <STDIN>;

  ##  do something with $in, I assume

  last if $in =~ /^\s*$/;     # empty or whitespace ends
}
```

But you might be trying to append the lines in which case change

```
$in = <STDIN>;
```

To

```
$in .= <STDIN>;
```

Or chomp it and add.

Or maybe you are looking more generally for a way to filter interactive prompts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

sub prompt {
  my ($text, $filter) = @_;
  while (1) {
    print $text;
    my $entry = <STDIN>; 
    chomp $entry;
    return $entry if $entry =~ $filter;
  }
}

prompt "Enter a digit: ", qw/^\d$/;
```